# Power of signal

Tags: power

In book, they say that power of signal $$y(t)=U\left [ \frac{1}{\pi}\cos(\omega_2-\omega_0)t+\frac{1}{2}\cos(\omega_2t)+\frac{1}{\pi}\cos(\omega_2+\omega_0)t \right ]$$ is $$P=\frac{U^{2}}{2R}(\frac{1}{\pi^{2}}+\frac{1}{2^{2}}+\frac{1}{\pi^{2}})$$
How did they get it? 
I know that P=U*U/R, but how to apply it here?

Comment: In what book? What kind of signal are we talking about? +1 for using the equation editor.

Comment: That's from Analogue telecommunications book. It is from one example involving modulations...

Comment: Good. So we can guess that _t_ is time and _U_ is probably voltage. What are ω2 and ω0 and R? Improve your question rather than add comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Power is proportional the average of V^2/R. Take your y(t), square it, and calculate the average. You'll find that the products of cosines of different frequencies gives another cosine (or sine) -- the average of those is zero. What's left is a set of constants (cosine(0)) with a factor of 1/2 in front of them.

Basically cos(a)*cos(b) = 1/2[cos(a+b) + cos(a-b)]. When a != b, the average of this is 0; when a=b, the only important term is the cos(a-b) which is equal to 1.